# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException (while working with REST API)

Tags: c#, async-await

> ExceptionSource: mscorlib, ExceptionMesage: An error occurred while
>   sending the request, ExceptionTrace:  at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   atSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at d__4.MoveNext().

For most of the times, I could get response from API. Otherwise, occasionally I get the above stated error.

I see some answers (authentication problem, wrong request URL and some others), but I have made sure all those are properly configured at my end.

Hope I can get some help here. Here is the section where the error appears:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(path, new StringContent(contents, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   Task<string> resultdata = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

   if (resultdata != null)
   {
       var resultContent = resultdata.Result;
       JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

       obj reference = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class Name>(resultContent, settings);                               
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you more information related to the exception? Error codes returned from the API? Because it looks like a generic async call that simply fails...

Comment: Thanks ! That is all the exception details I have got,
It's not actually returning any error code as it simply fails while sending the request itself...

Comment: Could you add the piece of code that is doing the call? Are you using cancellation tokens?

Comment: I do not have a clear idea on what a cancellation token is, but I believe haven't used one in my code..

Comment: Do you know if the error appears at the first PostAsync or the ReadAsStringAsync?

Comment: BTW, you should do this: string resultdata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: Error occurs at first PostAsync (It's not reaching the API server where it is been hosted)

Comment: Have you looked into what goes in the wire?